opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp:59:12: fatal error: cuda.h: No such file or directory
I want to install OpenCV V4.5.2 from source, so I cloned the repo and the contrib repo from github, checked out to that tag: 4.5.2 and tried to install OpenCV with these flags:
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D WITH_CUDA=ON -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON \
-D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON \
-D WITH_QT=OFF -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
-D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=OFF \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON\
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
-D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON -D HAVE_opencv_python3=ON\
-D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 \
-D CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda ..

I have CUDA 11.4 installed, I checked that using nvidia-smi and nvcc -V, and compiling OpenCV make -j10 works, but when I try to install it after sudo make install I get this error:
opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp:59:12: fatal error: cuda.h: No such file or directory
   59 | #  include <cuda.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

CMake finds CUDA on compilation:
-- Could NOT find CUDNN (missing: CUDNN_LIBRARY CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "7.5")
-- CUDA detected: 11.4
-- CUDA: Using CUDA_ARCH_BIN=3.5;3.7;5.0;5.2;6.0;6.1;7.0;7.5;8.0;8.6
-- CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_35,code=sm_35;-gencode;arch=compute_37,code=sm_37;-gencode;arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-gencode;arch=compute_52,code=sm_52;-gencode;arch=compute_60,code=sm_60;-gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61;-gencode;arch=compute_70,code=sm_70;-gencode;arch=compute_75,code=sm_75;-gencode;arch=compute_80,code=sm_80;-gencode;arch=compute_86,code=sm_86;-D_FORCE_INLINES

and the cuda.h header file is available in: /usr/local/cuda-11.4/include/cuda.h and /usr/local/cuda/include/cuda.h
cmake version 3.27.6
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0
kernel: 5.15.0-107-generic
NVIDIA-SMI 470.239.06   Driver Version: 470.239.06   CUDA Version: 11.4

Can you please tell me how can I solve this issue please? thanks

try http://forum.opencv.org, there's a cuda pro who might be able to help -- 4.5.x is fairly old. any reason for this?

@ChristophRackwitz 4.5.2 is used as I have other old packages using this version as a dependency to ensure compatibility.
